# USSD command return OK only

Tags: command, ussd

I am using USSD command with Huawei K3765 USB modem. For some USSD commands , it works great for me. But if I have a USSD session, i.e. if a USSD menu should appear, I can not read the USSD returned messaged. I have googled and tried :

- `AT+CMGF=0`   or  `AT+CMGF=1`
- `AT+CSCS="GSM"`  or  `AT+CSCS="IRA"`
- `at+cusd=1,"*225#",15`
- tried all the 3 ports that are associated with this modem

If I use the SIM card to external mobile phone and try this USSD, it should give me a message "if you need to recharge balance press 1, if you need to do Y, Press ..." etc. This message appears after 10 seconds.

But on the AT command and the same sim attached to Huawei USB modem , it returns only OK , no other messages appear.

Please advice. 
Thanks

Comment: hi did u find the answer

Comment: @waleed.makarem were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I finally got answer. the modem itself was not support USSD. when i changed the model , i got result.